Azure DevOps roll over unfinished stories
Disclaimer: I have read this post, however, I am still unsure about it.
What we did in the past:
When a story was unfinished at the end of the sprint, we duplicated it (along with the child task), rolled it over, kept the original estimate in the story and reduced the original estimate of the copied task to the remaining of the task in the last sprint. This has several issues:

(I think) statistics and calculations are unusable if this happens often
Devs completed a lot about this, because with the copy, all the comments and related
information was either duplicated or lost - no one knew where to post stuff. We have a policy of linking the user story to the PR - which one do you link in the end - there are two for the same thing.

What we do now:
We keep the original story where it is, and close the associated task (Set remaining to 0). We then copy the task, roll it over and enter the remaining from the original task.
This works a lot better, as there is now only one user story, which keeps all relevant information in one place. But, how does this affect velocity and other metrics? I am not too much in love with them - still I'd like to have them somewhat useable.
I spotted that this also creates some uncertainties - e.g. in the backlog. I have stories in the backlog from the last sprint, simply because it rolled over.
Would it be a feasible strategy to do the following?

Roll over the story to the next iteration
Keep the task in the current (elapsed) iteration
Create a new task under the story and roll it over (with the remaining as the new estimate)

Effectively what we do now, except that I also roll over the story (parent of the task)
Does this mess with statiscis (burndown, velocity) too much? Is there an inherent thing in AZDO which breaks by doing this? Unfortunately I was not able to find a "recommended" way in the docs, apart from copying (which I consider messy) or moving the entire story.

Asking if something is "OK" will attract opinion-based answers, which does not fit the Q&A style of this site. Very likely this question will be closed for being opinion-based. Can you [edit] your question to include the problem you are trying to solve with stories rolling from one sprint to another? That could be an answerable question.

@GregBurghardt I tried to adapt the question to include a clear question - I hope this is now okay. Imho, such things will unfortunately always be a little bit opinionated.

That is better, but you are still describing what you did and what you want to do. This would be off topic for this community. Questions about how to use a tool belong on StackOverflow. Instead, [edit] your question to focus on the problems you are having with what you are currently doing. Is it too much work? Is it skewing velocity or making velocity hard to track? Are too many stories rolling over?

And what is wrong with simply moving the story and its tasks into the next sprint?

The problem is not unique to AZDO.
There's no perfect solution, but what you should try to do is keep tasks to less than 1 day's worth of work.
A Story or Epic can cover multiple sprints, Tasks can be moved to the next sprint, but the stats will be mucked up.
If you keep the tasks to single day tasks then the idea is that you never have any half complete at the end of the day and hence at the end of the sprint.
Obviously there are always going to be a few, but with the small Tasks you only have half a days worth of inaccuracy.
Also, I would say that the burndown stats etc in scrum related methodologies are rarely accurate enough to be useful. Don't waste too much time worrying about estimates being accurate to the day/week/month. Instead just try to keep a measure of percentage done for the whole project and time elapsed.

While we do try to reduce the size of individual stories, it happens often that one story occupies at least 2-3 days of work. In such cases we divide the work into tasks which are "day-sized".
